# Azure AKS pull image from Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure-container-service, azure-container-registry

I have an Azure AKS cluster on which i'm trying to deploy a custom image that I have pushed to Azure Container Registry.

I have created a Service Principal and with that SP I have created my AKS. This SP also has Read Access on my ACR as described in below article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-aks

However my pods are not being created but give the message "Back-off pulling image"
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I was trying to use windows containers which is not yet supported on Azure AKS. Switched to linux image and worked fine